# Symbolic link in camel sftp endpoint

Tags: apache-camel, sftp, symlink

I have some problems using a filter attribute in an sftp-endpoint containing few symbolic links. My route looks as follows:

```
<route id="test1">
    <from uri="sftp://myhost/../../my_storage/dir_with_symlinks?username=user&amp;password=mypass&amp;recursive=true&amp;stepwise=false&amp;filter=#MyFileFilter"/>
    <to uri="file:/tmp/sftp/myout"/>
</route>
```

In `MyFileFilter.accept(GenericFile<T> file)` I get only all linked directories as `RemoteFile<T>` but the files in it won't be seen.
Obviously, I am missing some part of code. Any idea how could I solve the problem?

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: Thank You for your response. Camel version is 2.17.2

Comment: Try with latest, and if not check the source code with JSCH if there is something special needed to do a LIST which includes symbolic files